# Window sometimes retuns a blank page after reloading

Tags: javascript

When I open a child window from a parent window, I want it to reload after saving but sometimes the child window returns a blank page.

I want to reload the child window independent of the parent window action.
child window returns blank only in Chrome.

The code should work in both Chrome and firefox.

My code that reloads the window:

```js
setTimeout(() => location.reload(true), 2000);
```

Comment: Could you provide the context in which was this called?

Comment: I have added the above code in the SAVE button which makes HTTP request and after getting the response I want to reload my child window. My reload code should work in firefox and chrome.

Comment: Could you edit your answer and add the relevant code?

Comment: The code you have included is in the child window, correct?

Comment: Yes @PythonNerd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I could not put this code into a snippet because I needed multiple files, but I tested it and it worked.

index.html:

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  Parent Window
  <button>Open Child Window</button>
  <script>
    var button = document.querySelector("button"); //Get the button

    button.onclick = function() {
      window.open("child_window.html","_blank", "width=500,height=500,left=100,top=100,toolbar=0,status=0"); //Open the child window
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

child_window.html:

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    Child Window
    <button>Reload</button>
    <script>
      var button = document.querySelector("button"); //Get the button
      button.onclick = function(){
        //Reload the page after 2 seconds
        document.write("The page will reload in 2 seconds...");
        setTimeout(()=>{
          if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().includes("firefox")){
            window.location.reload(true);
          }else{
            window.location.reload();
          }
        }, 2000);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't know what the cause of your problem was, since this code works in Chrome. Let me know if it works.

Comment: window.location.reload() doesn't load css files in Firefox after reloading. window.location.reload(true) doesn't work in Chrome.

Comment: @KarimAli I edited it. Is this what you needed?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use [Firefox's `forceGet` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload#parameters) as it is experimental and not widely supported.

> Pass `true` to force a reload bypassing the cache.

Avoid using it if it's unnecessary.

Comment: child window returns blank only in Chrome.

Comment: @KarimAli But use `location.reload()` instead of `location.reload(true)`. There is no reason to use it if you're working in Chrome.

Comment: code should work in both Chrome and firefox.